# How to make Onboarding work with Scene Delegate in iOS13?

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, ios13, uiscenedelegate

I am trying to set up my onboarding screen in the SceneDelegate.

When I run the code below, it compiles, but just goes to a black screen.

They're many great onboarding tutorials for AppDelegate, but very few for the new SceneDelegate with iOS13. I took this tutorial and tried to apply it to SceneDelegate, but I can't get it to work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6t1woVd6RQ&t=537s

This is my scene delegate code.

```
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunched")
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc: UIViewController
        if launchedBefore
        {
            vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        }
        else
        {
            vc = launchStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Onboarding")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunched")
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    //    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
```

I've tried it both with commenting out the last guard statement and with not commenting it out.

Comment: You're creating the window incorrectly, so you're going to end up with a black screen. Working example here: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample/blob/master/RegistrationExample/AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the window incorrectly, so you're going to end up with a black screen. It would be a lot better to let the storyboard create the window for you, since you don't know how to do it. Just delete this line completely:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

You can also cut this line, as it is also otiose (the storyboard will do this for you as well):

```
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Your sole responsibility now is to set the value of `self.window?.rootViewController`. Note that you do not need to say

```
vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
```

because that is the root view controller already, given to you by the storyboard. Thus the only thing *you* need to do, in the architecture you've posited, is replace the root view controller in the situation where the user needs to be onboarded.

(See [my github repo](https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample/blob/master/RegistrationExample/AppDelegate.swift) for a working example.)

Comment: Thank you! This worked, and I tested it by deleting and reinstalling the app and making sure the onboarding process worked as well.

Comment: Cool, glad to help. I should mention that in my github example my architecture works the other way around from yours: the storyboard's initial view controller is the onboarding view controller, and the "normal" view controller is the one that we set in the scene delegate if the user _has_ onboarded already. However, it's up to you which way you want to play it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by matt, see his answer.

Just posting the correct code below for anyone trying to do Onboarding with storyboards in ios13.

```
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunched")
        let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc: UIViewController
        if launchedBefore
        {
            vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        }
        else
        {
            vc = launchStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "OnboardingScene")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunched")
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
```